# SpriteKit collision angle of line and circle is odd

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Suppose a circle is enclosed in a diamond, and the circle heads due right. I would expect a series of continual 90 degree angles as the circle draws a square within the diamond.

What I'm seeing, however, is that the circle eventually gets pushed toward the center of the diamond after one or two collisions. What's going on?

The line is set to dynamic -> NO.

[image: collision image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ball gets reflected symmetrically to its angle of approach assuming it's a completely elastic collision. That means, to get the behavior you are looking for, the ball would need to approach **exactly** from one line mid-point to the next without any loss of energy.

Sprite Kit's physics engine will not be able to handle these exact values. The energy after an elastic collision in Sprite Kit is not guaranteed to be conserved. There will be small inaccuracies in the physics engine's floating point calculations. Also the collision itself may not be resolved as a perfect point-to-point reflection, which means the ball might "slide," which will result in the angle of reflection changing.

However I would still expect to see more collisions then just one or two. Make sure the `restitution` of both objects is set to 1.0 and make sure the ball's `linear damping` is set to 0. `affectedByGravity` should obviously be false. `Friction` should be set to 0. You can try setting `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` to true.

If you need the behavior you described in you picture to last indefinitely, you will need to set the position and velocity manually.

Comment: What happens if there is linear damping during the collision? I'm actually looking for the ball to slow as it draws its square, but I didn't know that could also affect collisions. I'll test the other numbers you mentioned, but yes, gravity is false.

Comment: @StefanKendall Linear damping is like air resistance. It's just another external force. It will gradually slow the object down until it comes to a stop.

Comment: @StefanKendall Keep in mind, as the ball slows down it will most likely stop forming a square. Even small changes in the velocity will result in different reflection angles. If you still have issues you may want to post some code. Also are SKActions an option at all? You could easily animate the ball to each position and gradually slow it down but it wouldn't be real-time physics.

Comment: It was friction. Set friction to 0, and you get much more sensible collision angles for the example I described.

Comment: @StefanKendall Interesting, so indeed what happens is the ball slightly "slides" during each collision. Removing the friction from the system better conserves the elastic energy.

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior: incident angles near 90 degrees are always getting rounded to 90 coming off the wall, so that in the above diagram the square quickly turns into a single line crossing through the center. Disabling friction, setting `restitution` to 1.0, and enabling `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` all had no effect.